# Gimp AutoInputLevels in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, gimp

I am trying to recreate Gimp's AutoInputLevels (Colors>Levels>AutoInputLevels) in Imagemagick (need to batch process 1000 files). This is for an infrared image. I tried contrast_stretch, normalize and auto level, but they didn't help. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Edit: I won't be able to provide the representative images. However, when I say they didn't help, I am using other operations in GIMP. Doing the same (auto level and hard_light in ImageMagick) are not providing equivalent results.

Comment: Kindly share a representative input image and the corresponding GIMP Autolevelled result. It would also help if you could be more explicit about the exact commands you tried and what you mean by *"didn't help"*. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to @Mark Setchell's answer, I can tweak it a bit and get close using:

Input:

[image]

```
convert redhat.jpg -channel rgb -contrast-stretch 0.6%x0.6% im.png
```

ImageMagick Result:

[image]

GIMP AutoInputLevels Result:

[image]

And get a numerical comparison:

```
compare -metric rmse gimp.png im.png null:
```

363.484 (0.00554641)

which is about 0.5% difference.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I am using Python/wand module and the exact statement is "    image1.contrast_stretch(black_point=0.01, white_point=0.01, channel='all_channels')

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide a representative image, or expected result, I synthesised an image with three different distributions of red, green and blue pixels, using code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

w, h = 640, 480

# Synthesize red channel, mu=64, sigma=3
r = np.random.normal(64, 3, size=h*w)

# Synthesize green channel, mu=128, sigma=10
g = np.random.normal(128, 10, size=h*w)

# Synthesize blue channel, mu=192, sigma=6
b = np.random.normal(192, 6, size=h*w)

# Merge channels to RGB and round
RGB = np.dstack((r,g,b)).reshape((h,w,3)).astype(np.uint8)

# Save
Image.fromarray(RGB).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Then I applied the GIMP AutoInputLevels contrast stretch that you are asking about, and saved the result. The resulting histogram is:

[image]

which seems to show that the black-point and white-point levels have been set independently for each channel. So, in **ImageMagick** I guess you would want to separate the channels, apply some contrast-stretch to each channel independently and then recombine the channels along these lines:

```
magick input.png -separate -contrast-stretch 0.35%x0.7%  -combine result.png
```

[image]

If you provide representative input and output images, you may get a better answer.

Comment: Mark, you can do contrast stretch on separate channels by `convert input.png -channel rgb -contrast-stretch 0.35%x0.7% result.png`

Comment: @fmw42 That's simpler - thank you Fred. I suspect this question is not actually answered yet as no representative sample images have been shared, so I'll try and remember to update and simplify if/when the images arrive...